# How can I find all capitalization combinations of a String in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, capitalization

## Problem

I'm trying to find all of the possible combinations of capitalization for a String in Swift. For example, given the `String` "abc", I would want my method to return an `Array` of `String`s, like this: `["Abc", "aBc", "abC", "ABc", "abc", "ABC", "aBC", "AbC"]`. The formula for the possible number of capitalization combinations is like this:

> 2<sup>i</sup>

where `i` is the number of `Characters` in the `String`.

## Attempted Solutions

I've tried the following function, via an extension to the `String` type:

```swift
extension String {
func allPossibleCombinations() -> [String] {
        let string = self
        var result = [String]()
        var current = string
        result.append(current)
        for i in 0..<string.count {
            let index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
            if string[index].isLetter {
                current = current.replacingCharacters(in: index...index, with: String(current[index]).uppercased())
                result.append(current)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

This didn't work because it only returns capitalizations in order. For example, if I were to call this method on the `String` `"abc"`, it would return

```swift
["abc", "Abc", "ABc", "ABC"]
```

This should produce, as stated above, 8 different `Strings`. I suspect that I need to factor in an exponent to my code, or potentially some form of randomly choosing a `Character`.

## Similar questions that are NOT duplicates

- This `Python` question discusses the same issue: [Find all upper, lower and mixed case combinations of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144389/find-all-upper-lower-and-mixed-case-combinations-of-a-string). However, this does not work for my issue because it is in `Python`, not `Swift`.
- This `JavaScript` question talks about finding all combinations of a `String`: [Find all the combinations of a string Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722166/find-all-the-combinations-of-a-string-javascript). However, this is about general combinations, not capitalization ones, and is also in the wrong language.
- This `JavaScript` question discusses the same issue: [Find all lowercase and uppercase combinations of a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992204/find-all-lowercase-and-uppercase-combinations-of-a-string-in-javascript). However, this is in `JavaScript`, not `Swift`.
- This `C` question deals with the same issue: [Finding all capital letter combinations of random text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404757/finding-all-capital-letter-combinations-of-random-text). However, it is in `C`, not `Swift`.

## Summary

I am trying to make a function to get all possible capitalization forms of a `String`. I have a current attempt, but it is not sufficient as it does not produce all possible options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the integers in the range `0 ..< 2^length` and use the bits of the binary representation to tell you when to capitalize a letter:

```
extension String {
    func allPossibleCombinations() -> [String] {
        guard self.count > 0 else { return [] }
        var result = [String]()
        let lower = self.lowercased().map(String.init)
        let upper = self.uppercased().map(String.init)
        let length = self.count
        let limit = 1 << length
        for n in 0..<limit {
            var word = ""
            for i in 0..<length {
                if n & (1 << (length - i - 1)) != 0 {
                    word += upper[i]
                } else {
                    word += lower[i]
                }
            }
            result.append(word)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

---

### Examples

```
print("abc".allPossibleCombinations())

// ["abc", "abC", "aBc", "aBC", "Abc", "AbC", "ABc", "ABC"]

print("abcd".allPossibleCombinations())

// ["abcd", "abcD", "abCd", "abCD", "aBcd", "aBcD", "aBCd", "aBCD", "Abcd", "AbcD", "AbCd", "AbCD", "ABcd", "ABcD", "ABCd", "ABCD"]
```

---

### Alex's Swifty Version

In the comments, [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander) added this Swifty version using nested maps:

```
extension String {
    func allPossibleCombinations() -> [String] {
        guard self.count > 0 else { return [] }

        let length = self.count
        let limit = 1 << self.count
        
        return (0..<limit) .map { n in
            return self.enumerated()
                .map { i, c in (n & (1 << (length - i - 1)) != 0) ? c.uppercased() : c.lowercased() }
                .joined()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can replace a chunk of this with a `map` call: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/6ba89e4641b12798b9c472e6f930c8e2

Answer (score 0):

Use [`uniquePermutations`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Permutations.md).

```swift
import Algorithms

extension String {
  var capitalizationCombinations: [Self] {
    [false, true].flatMap {
      capitalize in repeatElement(capitalize, count: count)
    }
    .uniquePermutations(ofCount: count)
    .map { [lowercased = lowercased()] capitalizes in
      .init(
        zip(lowercased, capitalizes).map { character, capitalize in
          capitalize ? character.uppercased().first! : character
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could follow a recursive approach:

```swift
func capitalizations(of string: String) -> [String] {
    guard let first = string.first else { return [] }

    let firstLowercase = first.lowercased()
    let firstUppercase = first.uppercased()

    if string.count == 1 {
        return [firstLowercase, firstUppercase]
    } else {
        let partial = capitalizations(of: String(string.dropFirst()))
        return partial.map { firstLowercase + $0 } + partial.map { firstUppercase + $0 }
    }
}

print(capitalizations(of: "abc"))
// ["abc", "abC", "aBc", "aBC", "Abc", "AbC", "ABc", "ABC"]
```

Just take the first character, lowercase and uppercase it, and prepend it to capitalizations for the rest of the string.

Comment: Interestingly, after testing all three answers, this one is the fastest. Thank you for this answer!